# Conversion of std::string indices to integer in a std::vector

Tags: c++14, stdvector, stdstring

I want to access the last two index of std::string in a std::vector and then converting them to integer.But somehow I can not access it.Is there any optimal way for that?Thanks in advance

eg:say if the string is 6513494.Then the expected output for vector[i]will be 9 and 4

```
int n;string s;cin>>n;
vector<string>v;
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
{
    cin>>s;v.push_back(s);
}
for(int i=0;i<v.size();++i)if(v[s[s.size()-1]]-'0'==0&&v[s[s.size()-2]]-'0')cout<<v[i]<<endl;
```

Comment: The expression `v[s[s.size()-1]]-'0'` doesn't make any sense, and shouldn't compile. What are you trying to achieve here? Could you spell it out in plain English? Show an example input, and expected output for that input.

Comment: if the v[i]th string is 764 then how can i get 4 and 6 digits

Comment: `v[i].substr(v[i].size() - 2)` should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I believe it will help with what you wanted :)

```
    int n, val, ln;
    string s;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int>v;

    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        cin>>s;
        ln = s.size();
        val = (s[ln-2]-'0') * 10 + (s[ln-1]-'0');
        v.push_back(val);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<v.size();++i){
        printf("%d\n", v[i]);
    }
```